# sql does not work for specific query c#

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

I have this query:

```
DataTable ordersbetween = dm.getdatatablebyquery("select * from [reservering]"); // 'WHERE datumstart BETWEEN " + @row["datumstart"] + " AND " + @row["datumeind"] + "");
int totalorders = 0;
foreach (DataRow orders in ordersbetween.Rows)
{
      totalorders = totalorders + 1;
}

if (totalorders > 0)
{
     %> some orders where found <%
}
```

And somehow totalorders always remains 0 even though i have 8 entries in reservering.

But this query which is practicly the same works just fine.

```
DataTable tafellijst = dm.getdatatablebyquery("select * from [tafel]");
foreach (DataRow tafelrow in tafellijst.Rows) { %> 
    <option value="<%=tafelrow["id"]%>">nummer - <%=tafelrow["id"]%> | plaatsen - <%=tafelrow["plaatsen"]%></option>                                    
<% } %>
```

You can see ive currently simeplyfied the first query, the real query needs to select entries between specific DateTime's however every DateTime.tryparse() results in a datetime with the minimum value not my actual datetime.

Ive added the getdatatablebyquery method here:

```
            public DataTable getdatatablebyquery(string query)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionstring"].ConnectionString;
            con.ConnectionString = connectionString;

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                con.Close();
                return dt;
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException)
            {
                DataTable empty = new DataTable();
                return empty;
            }
            catch (SqlException)
            {
                DataTable empty = new DataTable();
                return empty;
            }
        }
```

Ive added the web.config here:

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="connectionstring" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\picobellodatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

This question was answered. 
Always use datatable.Rows.Count and check where your data is echod. I echod the data between an html  element so it became invisible!

Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: Why aren't you just using `ordersbetween.Rows.Count`? I see no benefit in iterating... As for the `DateTime` handling - you should be using parameterized SQL.

Comment: Why do you select all those data items? If you need the count, just select the count from the database.

Comment: How do you determine sql "does not work"? Put a breakpoint, inspect your `ordersbetween` DataTable.

Comment: @CodeCaster did both of those things, c# says every DataTable = null while data is returned on screen :/

Comment: Have you tried `DataTable ordersbetween = dm.getdatatablebyquery("select COUNT(*) from [reservering]");`? That should contain exactly one row, and will allow you to see if the problem is on the database side or client. If you still have 0 rows then maybe the problem is in `getdatatablebyquery`.

Comment: Have you stepped through `getdatatablebyquery` and checked if it is returning empty?

Comment: @Jonny just did that, if I add a breakpoint to see what happens in 'getdatatablebyquery' the connectionstring returns null and the query fails.

Comment: @Corne so now you need to figure out why your connection string is null? Has someone changed the configuration?

Comment: @Jonny but its only null with the breakpoint on without it, its fine ? how can that even be...

Comment: Check your `web.config` `<ConnectionStrings>`, check if db you are pointing to has been started.

Comment: @LIUFA ive checked the connectionstring its the same as the one for all other queries, which do actualy return data. ive also added it to the information above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change your code to

```
if (ordersbetween.Rows.Any())
{
     %> some orders where found <%
}
```

although `foreach` should emumerate the rows which is surprising that you are getting 0.
How confident are you that `getdatatablebyquery()` is doing that it is ought to?

Comment: ive added the getdatatablebyquery method to the information, but im confident it works fine since it has been for weeks.

Comment: This helped my towards the Answer and I finaly found it, IM SO HAPPY! after changing the datatable to select .Count it started to work. Only the first times I dident see it. This was because I was echoing the data between an html <select> element. #oeps well thanks everyone so much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is because of an exception.
Place a breakpoint on two `catch` opening braces and tell us the exception message.

Comment: added the breakpoints ran the code, no results but breakpoints dident trigger. :(

Comment: @Corne I thought that you said that the connection string is `null` and that is causing an exception?

Comment: @Jonny only when I add the breakpoint to the method, somehow it returns null then and i get no data. If i remove that breakpoint it runs except for the specific query. Its so strange like thats not supposed to be possible right! But I can add breakpoints on other places, since this example of adding the breakpoints to the catch still returned data.

Comment: It looks like when you are not debugging the connection string is `null`. As a result you get a `NullReferenceException` thrown, this then gets caught by the first `catch` block and then you get an empty table returned - which is exactly what you are seeing. You need to get the right connection string for your data source.

Comment: if the `DataTable` has no rows after `DataAdapter.Fill` it surely means that the DB table is empty. Have you checked the data inside the table?